# VisualVM running JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm

I can't get VisualVM working with eclipse, i was following these instructions
http://visualvm.java.net/download.html
and also these
http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html

The problem is that it cant see JDK location which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05", this happens when i try to run the application

[image]

Here is the original content of visualvm.conf file

http://pastebin.com/K9TnQb0G

Unfortunately my command line is somehow broken too(or I'm the one who dont know how to do it)

[image]

First I tryed to install JProbe but it wasnt working, then I tryed VisualVM and it also isn't working. How can i resolve this please? I wasted 5 hours and its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the JDK bin directory to the `PATH` environmental variable

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: It works, I had to delete everything else from path environmental variable and copy only "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin", also I had to run eclipse as administrator otherwise a got an error "cannot open requested application"

Comment: You shouldnt need to if the JDK appears first on the path. There's a JRE in `C:\Windows\System32`. See update

Answer (score 68):

Uncomment line 72 of your visualvm.conf file, and set the value:

```
#visualvm_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Comment: For anyone here, the visualvm.conf file is in etc directory, not in bin

Comment: If you are a MAC user you can find this file in `/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/etc`

Answer (score 10):

For MAC users, add below line to visualvm.conf file which can be located at `/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/etc`

```
visualvm_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<jdk version>/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 1):

For windowss its as simple as this:

```
<YourVisualVMUnzippedDir>\visualvm.exe --jdkhome "C:\YourPathToJDKDirForExample\Java\jdk1.6.0"
```

Source: https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html